# xpath query value comparison problem

Tags: xml, xpath, comparison

I have got a xml file that has a element, called property which contains a value element. Somhow in another connected system the value has changed from integer to decimal and therefor the comparison does not work anymore. Is there someway to do the comparison anyway? Xml and xpath will follow below.

xml:

```
<product>
   <properties>
       <property type="decimal" name="Volume" unit="l">
           <value>100,0</value>
       </property>
   </properties>
</product>
```

xpath:

```
/product/properties/property[@name='Volume' and value&lt;='200']
```

How do i write the xpath to work with the decimal value instead?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should accept answers on your previous questions fitst. I have no interest in answering for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `translate` to convert the

```
/product/properties/property[@name='Volume' and translate(value, ',', '.')<='200']
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Why does not a regular replace() work? Thanks.

Comment: Do note that @user270399 wrote *"How do i write the xpath to work with the decimal value instead?"*. So, it must be said that **number data type in XPath 1.0 is double**. The problem isn't the precision but the string mask of the number format.